# Unable to start SonarQube after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 with 'rule with UUID... not found

Tags: sonarqube

I am running Sonarqube 8.4.1 and updated the OS from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS.

Sonarqube fails to start with the following error in web.log

```
2020.09.26 09:51:37 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Update profile py/Sonar way
2020.09.26 09:51:37 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
org.sonar.server.exceptions.BadRequestException: Rule with UUID AXOWQWgnOEUJWGXZvgp- not found
```

The database is Postgresql 12.

I tried updating sonar to 8.4.2 but get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by disabling the python plugin (we don't need it and error was related to python).  To disable it I ran these commands:

```
cd  ~/sonarqube-8.4.2/extensions/plugins (wherever you have sonarqube installed)
mv sonar-python-plugin-2.13.0.7236.jar sonar-python-plugin-2.13.0.7236.bak
```

I then started sonarqube and it started up fine after showing some INFO messages about disabling python.